# Heroku outputs "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, bitbucket

The following deployment procedure updates my source code appropriately on Bitbucket but doesn't deploy properly on Heroku.

Command sequence:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some commit"
git push -u origin master
git push heroku master
```

Changing a simple html file gets reflected in Bitbucket but not on Heroku.

It simply outputs `Everything up-to-date`, when it shouldn't be.

Here is the state of things:

```
>git branch
* master

>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

>git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date

>git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
```

Where should I be looking to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means there's likely a different issue in your actual application rendering the template. If heroku says your git repo is up to date, it is. That is not an error.

What this means is that you should be looking for issues in your application that are responsible for RENDERING that template, and ensure things there are working properly.

Comment: Hmm I'm not using a template engine. I literally deleted an `h1` tag from an HTML file which no longer shows up on Bitbucket but somehow manifests itself on Heroku.

Comment: Heroku doesn't directly serve html files. You must be using a library / tool / something to return the HTML document through the request :o

Comment: Yes, Express.js `response.sendFile` @rdegges

Comment: Do you have a CDN / cache in front of that? That might be the issue.

Comment: I don't... It's a pretty basic Express installation

Comment: Would you mind posting the code and a link to the site?